# change jobtracker and tasktracker logging to 'Daily Rolling File Appender'

Tags: hadoop, log4j, cloudera

Since with 'Daily Rolling File Appender', we are not able to give MaxBackupIndex, i want to use 'Rolling File Appender' for Job Tracker and Task Tracker daemon logs. How can i do that? Following is the log4j i am using. (I am using hadoop cdh4beta2)

```
# Define some default values that can be overridden by system properties
hadoop.root.logger=INFO,console
hadoop.log.dir=.
hadoop.log.file=hadoop.log

# Define the root logger to the system property "hadoop.root.logger".
log4j.rootLogger=${hadoop.root.logger}, EventCounter

# Logging Threshold
log4j.threshold=ALL

# Null Appender
log4j.appender.NullAppender=org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender

#
# Rolling File Appender - cap space usage at 5gb.
#
hadoop.log.maxfilesize=100MB
hadoop.log.maxbackupindex=3
log4j.appender.RFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.log.file}
log4j.appender.RFA.MaxFileSize=${hadoop.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.RFA.MaxBackupIndex=${hadoop.log.maxbackupindex}

log4j.appender.RFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern format: Date LogLevel LoggerName LogMessage
log4j.appender.RFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
# Debugging Pattern format
#log4j.appender.RFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{2} (%F:%M(%L)) - %m%n


#
# Daily Rolling File Appender
#

log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.log.file}

# Rollver at midnight
log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

# 30-day backup
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.DRFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern format: Date LogLevel LoggerName LogMessage
log4j.appender.DRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
# Debugging Pattern format
#log4j.appender.DRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{2} (%F:%M(%L)) - %m%n


#
# console
# Add "console" to rootlogger above if you want to use this 
#

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n
#
# TaskLog Appender
#

#Default values
hadoop.tasklog.taskid=null
hadoop.tasklog.iscleanup=false
hadoop.tasklog.noKeepSplits=4
hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize=100
hadoop.tasklog.purgeLogSplits=true
hadoop.tasklog.logsRetainHours=12

log4j.appender.TLA=org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogAppender
log4j.appender.TLA.taskId=${hadoop.tasklog.taskid}
log4j.appender.TLA.isCleanup=${hadoop.tasklog.iscleanup}
log4j.appender.TLA.totalLogFileSize=${hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize}

log4j.appender.TLA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.TLA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n

#
#Security appender
#
hadoop.security.logger=INFO,console
hadoop.security.log.maxfilesize=100MB
hadoop.security.log.maxbackupindex=3
log4j.category.SecurityLogger=${hadoop.security.logger}
hadoop.security.log.file=SecurityAuth.audit
log4j.appender.RFAS=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.RFAS.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.security.log.file}
log4j.appender.RFAS.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RFAS.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
log4j.appender.RFAS.MaxFileSize=${hadoop.security.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.RFAS.MaxBackupIndex=${hadoop.security.log.maxbackupindex}

#
# Daily Rolling Security appender
#
log4j.appender.DRFAS=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.DRFAS.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.security.log.file}
log4j.appender.DRFAS.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DRFAS.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
log4j.appender.DRFAS.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

#
# hdfs audit logging
#
hdfs.audit.logger=ERROR,NullAppender
hdfs.audit.log.maxfilesize=100MB
hdfs.audit.log.maxbackupindex=3
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=${hdfs.audit.logger}
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=false
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/hdfs-audit.log
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c{2}: %m%n
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.MaxFileSize=${hdfs.audit.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.MaxBackupIndex=${hdfs.audit.log.maxbackupindex}

#
# mapred audit logging
#
mapred.audit.logger=INFO,console
mapred.audit.log.maxfilesize=100MB
mapred.audit.log.maxbackupindex=3
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.AuditLogger=${mapred.audit.logger}
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.AuditLogger=false
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/mapred-audit.log
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c{2}: %m%n
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.MaxFileSize=${mapred.audit.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.MaxBackupIndex=${mapred.audit.log.maxbackupindex}

# Custom Logging levels

#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=DEBUG

# Jets3t library
log4j.logger.org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service=ERROR

#
# Event Counter Appender
# Sends counts of logging messages at different severity levels to Hadoop Metrics.
#
log4j.appender.EventCounter=org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter

#
# Job Summary Appender 
#
# Use following logger to send summary to separate file defined by 
# hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.file :
# hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.logger=INFO,JSA
# 
hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.logger=${hadoop.root.logger}
hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.file=hadoop-mapreduce.jobsummary.log
hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxfilesize=100MB
hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxbackupindex=3
log4j.appender.JSA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.JSA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.file}
log4j.appender.JSA.MaxFileSize=${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.JSA.MaxBackupIndex=${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxbackupindex}
log4j.appender.JSA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.JSA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress$JobSummary=${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.logger}
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress$JobSummary=false
```